# Iframe not loading page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I have a local html file that contains only an iframe.
The iframe has the src attribute pointing to a certain url containing an angular web application.

The problem I have is that the page stays blank. The iframe does seem load because I can inspect the inner html of the framed webpage but it looks like the angular app doesn't bootstrap or something because no content is rendered.

I've seen many similar posts about iframes that don't load and the problem is always that the target page denies iframe usage via some http header. This is not the case, there is no X-Frame-Options or CSP header present.

So, if the server does allow the page to be used in iframes, what could be the reason that nothing is displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you improve the question by adding the code that you have tried?

Comment: @AzizStark There is no code, just an html page with an iframe inside the body and a src attribute pointing to a url.